# Wait until all promises finished

Tags: node.js

How can I know when all promises inside the for loop finished executing? Is there a better way to do it?

```
for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
  request(array[index], function (error, response, body) {
    promise1().then(result1 => {
      if (result1 !== 0) {
        promise2().then(result2 => {
          promise3(result2);
        }
      } else {
        promise3(result1);
      }
    });
  });
}

console.log('all promises finished');
```

Comment: If you import the async module you can create an async waterfall to handle the promises sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is made easier by transforming the code to use `async`/`await` to map the items into promises, then using the standard `Promise.all()` function to wait for all of the promises to resolve:

```
// promisified request()
const requestP = item =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(item, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve({ response, body });
    });
  });

const processItem = async item => {
  const { response, body } = await requestP(item);
  const result1 = await promise1(/* this probably uses response or body? */);
  if (result1 !== 0) {
    const result2 = await promise2();
    return await promise3(result2);
  } else {
    return await promise3(result1);
  }
};

const promises = array.map(processItem);

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log("all promises finished");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep adding the `promises` you create in a list inside the `for loop`.

Once you are done with your loop, you can register a `Promise.all` method.

```
let list_of_promises = [];

for(...) {
    list_of_promises.push(
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject)) {
            ...
        }
    )
}

Promise.all(list_of_promises).then(function(data)) {
    ...
}.catch(function(err) {
    ...
});
```

If all your `promises` get resolved, `.then` method will be called.

Note: Even if one of your promise fails, it will go inside the `.catch` method.